# Rails equivalent of respond_to |format| with a straight render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rendering, http-status-code-404, actioncontroller

I'm working with ActiveResource a lot so my service models are only using XML.  Thus, I have no need for a respond_to block, I literally just `render :xml => @model`

I can't however figure out how to render a 404 header using this.  I've had to resort to respond_to, which I think adds a few unnecessary method calls.  Here's what I'm using:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if (record_found)
    render :xml => @some_record
  else
    format.xml{ head :not_found }
  end
end
```

but I just want something like `render :xml => head :not_found` which doesn't work.  Can anyone tell me the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
render {:xml => "Record not found", :status => :not_found }
```

Comment: you're getting lots of points from my questions!!  Thanks, I didn't realize a straight string would work